# How to insert hyperlink without underline to Win32 RichEdit?

Tags: c++, winapi, hyperlink, underline, richedit

I added a link to RichEdit, use CFM_LINK/CHARFORMAT2 structure. But I can't figure out how to remove the underline effect. I tried:

```
SendMessage(richEditHWND, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, FALSE, NULL);
SendMessage(richEditHWND, EM_SETEDITSTYLEEX, 0, SES_EX_HANDLEFRIENDLYURL);

CHARFORMAT2 cf2;
memset(&cf2, 0, sizeof(CHARFORMAT2));
cf2.dwMask = CFM_LINK| CFM_UNDERLINE | CFM_COLOR | CFM_LINKPROTECTED;
cf2.dwEffects = CFE_LINK| CFE_UNDERLINE | CFE_LINKPROTECTED;
cf2.crTextColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
cf2.bUnderlineType = CFU_UNDERLINENONE;
SendMessage(richEditHWND, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, (LPARAM)&cf2);
```

But it don'n work.
Another way is set underline color to white color, which is the RichEdit   background color, but it is a hacky way, make character like q, j,... being cut apart, also show the line when select text.
So what's the correct way to do this?
**Note:** I'm using `RICHEDIT50W` class.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a *friendly-name hyperlink*. These let you specify arbitrary text (along with its own color and formatting) that is used for display, and the actual URL is hidden.

> By default, friendly-name hyperlink text is also displayed in blue
>   with a blue underline unless the name text is formatted with an
>   explicit color. Explicit formatting takes precedence

The displayed text needs to have the `CFE_LINK` and `CFE_LINKPROTECTED` styles, along with explicit color and formatting styles. You then set the URL using the [`ITextRange2::SetURL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh768661(v=vs.85).aspx) method.

The MSDN blog post [RichEdit Friendly Name Hyperlinks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murrays/archive/2009/09/24/richedit-friendly-name-hyperlinks.aspx) has a more detailed description of how to use them.

Comment: Not worked. I updated my code in the question. In your link, they say I can change color of the link, not able to hide underline. The other comments on that page also confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem recently and I just found that it's a bug of Richedit library. When I updated it from v4.1 to v5.0 the underline could be removed with no issues

Answer (score -2):

Try sending an EM_AUTOURLDETECT message to the RichEdit control with wParam=0, lParam=0

"Specify 0 to disable automatic link detection...": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787991(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It not me vote down. I tried that before and dont work

Comment: Where is EM_AUTOURLDETECT in your edit? Try SendMessage(richEditHWND, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, 0, 0);

Comment: I said I tried that at above comment. By the way, richedit control don't enable detect url by default.